# Update query in VB.Net not updating

Tags: mysql, vb.net, sql-update

```
Dim Query As String

    Dim con As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection("server=localhost;Database=sidhay;User ID=root;Password=1234;")
    con.Open()

    Query = "UPDATE pendingloans SET PLStatus ='" + status.Text
    Query = Query + "' WHERE MemberID = " + loanid.Text

    Dim cmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(Query, con)
    Dim i As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    If (i > 0) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Success!")
    Else
         MessageBox.Show("Failed!")
    End If
    con.Close()
```

I need help with my update function, it isn't working. There are no errors but when I try to update, it always shows Failed! Anyone knows how to solve this?

Comment: You need to have try..catch block in catch you can have failed message and in try keep your code. In above approach well you need not to check the way you are checking. Have try...catch if any error come that will go in catch and you show your custom message.

Comment: Perhaps `WHERE MemberID = ...` condition is not met? Can u run the query directly against server and see if it executes? Or as a test run `SELECT * FROM pendingloans WHERE MemberID = ...<that member ID u're using>`

Comment: What data type is MemberID in your database?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**
Your script seems fine! Just check if a record with the ID specified does actually exist in the database

Comment: Tried this one but still Failed.   Dim con As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection("server=localhost;Database=sidhay;User ID=root;Password=1234;")
        con.Open()

        Dim query As String = "UPDATE pendingloans SET PLStatus ='" + status.Text
        query = query + "' WHERE MemberID = " + loanid.Text

        Dim cmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(query, con)
        Dim i As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        If (i > 0) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Success!")
        Else
             MessageBox.Show("Failed!")
        End If
        con.Close()

Comment: Doesn't give me an error but shows my message box that contains my "Failed!" custom message.

Comment: ok first of, my bad, i didn't see that you had already declared the query variable hence i though there was a syntax error.

Comment: second, can you try verifying if there does exist a record in your database with an id that is in `loanid.Text`. Maybe your query cant find the record with an id you specified.